# A naive question about a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a second order PDE:
$$(-\partial^2+m^2)f(x)=0.\tag{1}$$
The solution to this equation is:
$$f(x)=C_1e^{-m x}+C_2e^{mx}\tag{2}.$$
I want to obtain this solution by Fourier transformation. Taking
$$f(x)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx}f(k),$$
then we have 
$$(k^2+m^2)f(k)=0.\tag{3}$$
Now the problem is that, to recover the solution Eq.(2), it seems that we need to ask
$$f(k)=C_1*2\pi\delta(k-im)+C_2*2\pi\delta(k+im)
=\tilde{C}_1\delta(k-im)+\tilde{C}_2\delta(k+im).\tag{4}$$

While I am clear that Eq.(3) is an "on-shell" condition equation, I do not see clearly why we must enforce a delta function on $f(k)$.

Comment: When you take the Fourier transform you implicitly assume that the Fourier transform exists in the first place. However the Fourier transform of (2) does not exist when $m$ is real.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your comment. But why does not the Fourier transform of (2) exist when $m$ is real?

Comment: Because $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm d}x f(x) e^{-ikx}$ and $f(x) = e^{\pm mx}$ grows exponentially fast as $x\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: @Winther I see. Thanks.